# Time is being changed when passing the intent extra to the Service class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass JSON string to the Service class but I noticed the time is being changed there(in the onHandelIntent method) and I am always getting an  old timeStamp. I have cleaned my project but nothing changed.

This part is being called from onLocationChanged method in the inner class "MyLocationListener" in the MainActivity:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        double pLong = location.getLongitude();
        double  pLat = location.getLatitude();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
        String formatted = sdf.format(location.getTime());

        // If I pass the data like this it works but I have to add a constructor
        //   for the class and work with Thread as well as AsyncTask.
        // String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted); 
        // PostData sender = new PostData(jSONString);
        // sender.timer();

        String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);      
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostData.class);
        intent3.putExtra("json_data", jSONString);

        // Here I am getting the right timeStamp.
        startService(intent3);
    }
```

convertToJSON method:

```
private String convertToJSON(double pLong, double pLat, String formatted) {
    //envelop the data in JSON format.
    Data d = new Data(pLat, pLong, formatted,route_number);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, new DataSerializer()).create();
    String a = gson.toJson(d);
    return a;
}
```

PostData class:

```
public class PostData extends IntentService {

    public PostData() {
        super("some");    
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {    
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data"); //here I am always getting this time "18:37:49"        
  }
}
```

The passed JSON string in the onHandelIntent():

```
{
   "latitude":47.86907815,
   "longitude":13.66554789,
   "formatted":"23.04.2015 18:37:49",
   "route":4
}
```

Comment: I think I am not understanding you at all. You mean that a String timestamp is changing? :S

Comment: Yes just the value of the timeStamp is being changed and I am always getting there always this vlaue`23.04.2015 18:37:49` when passing it to the `PostData` class, strange behaviour.

Comment: With the code you presented, it makes no sense. Could you add some more, especially when you get this data from JSON and before converting it to String?

Comment: Yeah for me this question has no sense, It is pretty imposible to change the timestamp if you do not manipulate it because it is a String

Comment: @Rafael: As I said I have debugged it and I can see the time value  at this line `startService(intent3);`  in intent3 the current time is there. I am getting the time from location.getTime() in the onChanedLocation method. I added more code

Comment: What is your goal here? To get the current time?

Comment: I want to send the data(Long, latit, time and the strongest wifi access point) in the background  to the server every 60 seconds.

Comment: I understand that. But what is `time` in `data(Long, latit, time and wifi point)` ? Do you want send the exact time at the moment?

Comment: Yes it is the current time to know when the data was recorded.